# How to correctly stop overflowing and maintain the responsiveness

Tags: html, css, flexbox, css-grid

I have made a sticky header using flexbox then using a grid for the body. But applying height to grid items makes the page overflow which I don't want. I have figured I can solve this overflowing by `calc(100vh - the height of header)` but eventually the height of the header will change if I change the resolution to that of mobile making the new height useless.

The other solution I can think of is by explicitly adding a height to the header but I think that is not the right solution to my problem
https://codepen.io/iwantroca-the-flexboxer/pen/ZEayyqp

```css
* {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html {
  font-size: 17px;
  font-family: poppins;
}

body {
  min-height: 100vh;
}

header {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 20px;
  background: rgb(139, 48, 48);
  color: white;
}

header>h2 {
  font-style: italic;
  font-weight: lighter;
  margin-left: 3em;
}

.app_logo {
  font-size: 2.3em;
  margin-right: 10px;
  color: rgba(187, 190, 136, 0.774);
}


/* MAIN */

main {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 4fr;
}

#projects_bar {
  background: red;
  height: 100vh;
}

#tasks_bar {
  background: yellow;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
  <title>Todo-App</title>
</head>

<body>
  <header>
    <i class="fa-solid fa-check-double app_logo"></i>
    <h1>Todo App</h1>
    <h2>Get things done</h2>
  </header>
  <main>
    <nav id="projects_bar">
      <h2>Projects</h2>
    </nav>
    <div id="tasks_bar">
      <h2>Tasks</h2>
    </div>
  </main>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With your current structure why not just make `header` 10vh and `main` 90vh. This means that `#projects_bar` and `#tasks_bar` will also be 90vh also because 100vh (what you previously had) will cause overflow on the y-axis.

You can also add `overflow-y: hidden;` on the body to make it not scroll when switching device types.

**Edit ~** mentioned in comments, same result without setting a height to the header. Remove all heights, and set height on `body` to `100vh`. `min-height: 100vh;` is not the same as `height: 100vh;` so you need to establish that first. Then you can just set `height: 100%;` to `main`, and it will fill the remaining viewport.

```css
* {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html {
  font-size: 17px;
  font-family: poppins;
}

body {
  height: 100vh;
  min-height: 100vh;
  overflow-y: hidden;
}

header {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 20px;
  background: rgb(139, 48, 48);
  color: white;
}

header>h2 {
  font-style: italic;
  font-weight: lighter;
  margin-left: 3em;
}

.app_logo {
  font-size: 2.3em;
  margin-right: 10px;
  color: rgba(187, 190, 136, 0.774);
}


/* MAIN */

main {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 4fr;
  height: 100%;
}

#projects_bar {
  background: red;
}

#tasks_bar {
  background: yellow;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
  <title>Todo-App</title>
</head>

<body>
  <header>
    <i class="fa-solid fa-check-double app_logo"></i>
    <h1>Todo App</h1>
    <h2>Get things done</h2>
  </header>
  <main>
    <nav id="projects_bar">
      <h2>Projects</h2>
    </nav>
    <div id="tasks_bar">
      <h2>Tasks</h2>
    </div>
  </main>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Earlier I was looking at some templates and got confused when I saw them working fine without any height set to header and still being responsive throughout.

Comment: @Iwantroca Yup, see edits!

Comment: @Iwantroca don't be shy to ask if you have any questions at all.

Comment: really appreciate your help. I have understood quite a bit thanks to you. Right now I am designing the app further more.